# I'm trying to get the two cels the same size but the left one stays bigger

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to get the two tables-cels to take up an equal amount of space but the one on the left stays bigger than the right one.

I entered this code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5DF4/) and it looks fine, but it's lop-sided on my site.

Anybody have an idea of what I'm missing?

here's the html:

```
        <div class="terms">    
        <div id="c1">
        <h3>This is the left side</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="c2">
        <h3>This is the right side</h3>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div> 
        </div>               

</div>       
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.terms {
    margin-top: 25px;
    clear:both;
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
    border-spacing: 35px 75px 35px 75px;
}

#c1, #c2, #c3 {
    display:table-cell;
    font-family:'Lato', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #787878;
    line-height: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#c1, #c2, #c3 h3 {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

p {
    color: #828282;
    font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: by the way I've tried firefox, chrome and safari all with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

More comments than answer, but alas, my reputation is too low to comment.
I'd really have to pull it up in the element inspector in the browser to see where the styles are coming from, something may be overwriting your styles.

But you could also maybe try to add

```
max-width:50%;
```

to your css elements for those columns.

Comment: What size are they getting. It's hard to figure out with actual "broken" markup. If one is getting shrunk, try setting min-width to 50%, you could set width to 50% but I've had odd results where I needed to force either min or max.
If you use your browsers element inspector you can tell alot. I like firefox's 3D inspector, someone showed me that recently and it's pretty helpful in certain cases.